# link send button to ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I have following code in my view file:

```
<button id="send"">Send</button>
```

and

```
$('input[name="managerelradio"]').change(function(){
  var manageradiorel = $('input[name="managerelradio"]:checked').val();
  console.log(manageradiorel);
  var module_id='<?php echo $model->id;?>';
  $.ajax({
    url: '/cabinet/intranet/changeStatus', //actionChangeStatus
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {'val':manageradiorel, 'module_id':module_id},
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log(manageradiorel);
      console.log('id');
    },
    success: function (r) {
      console.log(r);
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

I need to execute the second code(ajax request), if user presses `send` button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to write your AJAX code within the button click event.

```
$("#send").on("click", function() {   // Button click event
    var manageradiorel = $('input[name="managerelradio"]:checked').val();
    console.log(manageradiorel);
    var module_id='<?php echo $model->id;?>';
    $.ajax({
     ..........
     ..........
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen `click` event

```
<button id="send"">Send</button>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send').click(function(){

                       var manageradiorel = $('input[name="managerelradio"]:checked').val();
                       console.log(manageradiorel);
                       var module_id='<?php echo $model->id;?>';
                       $.ajax({
                           url: '/cabinet/intranet/changeStatus', //actionChangeStatus
                           type: 'POST',
                           cache: false,
                           data: {'val':manageradiorel, 'module_id':module_id},
                           beforeSend: function() {
                               console.log(manageradiorel);
                               console.log('id');
                           },
                           success: function (r) {
                               console.log(r);
                               console.log('success');
                           },
                           error: function (e) {
                               console.log(e);
                           }
                       });

                   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#send').on('click',function(){
   // do your ajax call here
});
```